# Difference between IERC20 and just address

Tags: ethereum, solidity

There are two ways of declaration ERC20 in other contracts:

1. `IERC20 public token`, and then connecting to it like `token.transfer`;
2. `address public token`, and then connecting to it like `IERC20(token).transfer`.

Is there any difference between these two ways of declaration? If so, what is more preferred for usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is during compilation, when the compiler would give you an error if you tried to use one type where the other is required.

In terms of runtime, they are both (160-bit) ethereum addresses.

In your example, it makes more sense to use the type `IERC20`, because that is the intended type of the variable `token`.

Comment: so basically IERC20 type just saves me some time while testing, if by the accident i'll give wrong address.. i got it, thank you!

Comment: @invisiblecat: Exactly the opposite. There is **NO** runtime difference, so your tests will act exactly the same regardless of what type you use. If anything, it will save you time while writing your code.